# Defining a contract that all spiders in a project must test against

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to define an "uber"-contract in a scrapy project that all spiders of that project must test against?

My project consists of around 50 spiders that all scrape separate websites but return the same Items. It would therefore be very interesting to be able to define one global contract that each spider can be tested against (with the exception of the URL to be scraped of course).

Is this doable? It seems that I'm limited to defining a [contract](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) on a per spider basis.

Comment: do you mean a contract to test the items scraped? if so, you could add a pipeline or extension that validates them and discard/logs accordingly.

Comment: That would be a good way of achieving the same result, thanks for the good idea.